# How t create JqueryUI dialog for each record in json

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, dialog

I have to get data from database and for each record i want to show different dialog box.
I tried below code but not working...Should i need to create dynamically?

What is missing in my code?

```
 $.getJSON("jsonfile.php", function(json){ 
    $.each(json, function (key, val) {
      $.each(val, function (key, val1) {
             if(key=='rem_doc_deal_ref')
          {
        $('#rem_doc_deal_ref').text(val1);
          }
       $( "#dialog_rem_doc" ).dialog({
       buttons: {
      "Ok!": function() {
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
       },
      Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
       }
     }
    });
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my JSON

```
[{"id":"27","rem_doc_deal_ref":"RH-D-139"},{"id":"43","rem_doc_deal_ref":"RH-D-140"},{"id":"41","rem_doc_deal_ref":"RH-D-144"},{"id":"55","rem_doc_deal_ref":"RH-D-157"},{"id":"33","rem_doc_deal_ref":"RH-D-158"},{"id":"22","rem_doc_deal_ref":"RH-D-233"}}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="dialog_rem_doc" title="Reminder Alert" style="display:none;">
    <span id="rem_doc_deal_ref"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: here is my html  <div id="dialog_rem_doc" title="Reminder Alert" style="display:none;"><span id="rem_doc_deal_ref"></span></div>

Comment: Yes, you need to create dynamic elements. You're simply overwriting the same element each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to add the dialogs dynamically.

```
$.getJSON("jsonfile.php", function(json){ 
    $.each(json, function (key, val) {
        var deal_ref = val.rem_doc_deal_ref;
        $('<div title="Reminder Alert" style="display: none;">' + deal_ref + '</div>')
            .appendTo('#container').
            .dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Ok!": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
```

I left out the `id` attribute of the DIV, since they need to be unique. Since these are dynamically added, I don't know if you need IDs at all. If you do, you can make unique IDs by appending `key` to a prefix. I also omitted the `<span>`; it looks like that was just there as a place to put the html in your original code, but now it's not necessary. You can add it back to the HTML being appended.

And notice that you don't need to use `$.each` to process the contents of the objects in the JSON array. Just access them by property name, `val.rem_doc_deal_ref`.